# Creating a filtered PHAssetCollection of Albums fails

Tags: ios, swift4, photosframework

I need to create a filtered collection of smartAlbums for display in a UITable.
I have previously tried various approaches to casting an unfiltered collection to a mutable form and deleting the ones I wish to exclude, then recasting back to a PHFetchResult. All of those attempts failed.

I am now trying to use PHFetch options to filter albums with a key of "localizedTitle" which is specifically allowed (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phfetchoptions). However, when I try the following test case code of trying to exclude the "Videos" smart folder, I get zero count results in newAlbums.  I also get zero results when I set the predicate to %K == %@.  The correct answer should have been 15 in the former and 1 in the latter.  Why is my predicate failing to select the proper results?  I do not wish to save the new collection back into the library, just use it for temporary display, so I did not try a Request call (maybe I misunderstand the framework here?)

I have searched S/O and developer.apple and the only examples of working code are for filtering individual media (photos or video), not for selecting smartAlbums.

```
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "localizedTitle", "Videos")
    fetchOptions.predicate = p1
    let newAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .albumRegular, options: fetchOptions)
```

Comment: Has anyone used a Transient Collection to achieve this kind of result? Given that transient collections, like regular result collections are immutable, I don't see how to build the collection I want as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach I found which I have validated to work.  Many thanks to Michael https://stackoverflow.com/a/46145638/4945371

First add this little method which returns not a PHCollectionList, but an array!

```
private func fetchSmartCollections(with: PHAssetCollectionType, subtypes: [PHAssetCollectionSubtype]) -> [PHAssetCollection] {
    var collections:[PHAssetCollection] = []
    let options = PHFetchOptions()
    options.includeHiddenAssets = false

    for subtype in subtypes {
        if let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: with, subtype: subtype, options: options).firstObject {
            collections.append(collection)
        }
    }
    return collections
}
```

Then create an array of desired smart albums:

```
    let subtypes:[PHAssetCollectionSubtype] = [
        .smartAlbumFavorites,
        .smartAlbumLongExposures,
        .smartAlbumSelfPortraits,
        .smartAlbumRecentlyAdded
        // .smartAlbumUserLibrary,
        // .smartAlbumPanoramas,
        // .smartAlbumLivePhotos,
        // .smartAlbumBursts,
        // .smartAlbumDepthEffect,
        // .smartAlbumScreenshots,
    ]
```

Finally,

```
        smartAlbumsArray = fetchSmartCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtypes: subtypes)
```

instead of some variant of:

```
    smartAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .albumRegular, options: smartAlbumOptions)
```